# Convert the "facet_filter" query into pyes format

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, pyes

I have a following query and I want to change that query into PyES:

```
{
    "facets": {
        "participating-org.name": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "participating-org.name"
            },
            "facet_filter": {
                "term": {
                    "participating-org.role": "funding"
                }
            },
            "nested": "participating-org"
        }
    }
}
```

I have searched in PyES documentation about this "facet_filter" but couldn't come up with good query in PyES.
 
**So need some help for converting this JSON query into PyES format.**

Answer (score 0):

This should work. But its untested. I use it similar in another code.

```
from pyes.facets import FacetFactory, TermFacet, ANDFacetFilter
facet_factory = FacetFactory()
facet_filter = ANDFacetFilter(TermFilter('category'))
term_facet = TermFacet(
            field='attributes',
            facet_filter=facet_filter,
            name='yourfacet',
            size=100,
            )

facet_factory.add(term_facet)
```